# Netty tuning for a high performance UDP server

Tags: java, performance, netty, nio

I have a UDP server that uses Netty.

The architecture is pretty simple:

At startup, a single `Channel` is created and bound. The pipeline consists of a single handler that dispatches incoming UDP packets to a thread pool. UDP packets are therefore processed concurrently. Processing a UDP packet involves some IO (e.g. accessing a database). After a UDP packet is processed, a response is sent back.

I'm looking for information to improve performance since the server doesn't meet our throughput requirements.

Some of my code:

```
Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
    .group(new EpollEventLoopGroup(1))
    .channel(EpollDatagramChannel.class)
    /* Is the following allocator recommended? */
    .option(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT)
    .handler(channelInitializer);

ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.bind(host, port).await();
```

My executor service:

```
executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
    nbWorkerThreads, /* Optimal number of threads? */
    nbWorkerThreads,
    0L,
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

The code I use to send a response back:

```
ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(new DatagramPacket(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(bytes),  ctx.sender()));
```

Comment: I recommend you use the argument less constructor of `EpollEventLoopGroup` as the amount of thread it starts is automatically calculated.

Comment: @Ferrybig It's a UDP server, only one Channel is created. Therefore, there is no need to use a multi threaded event loop group.

Comment: The advantage of a multi-threaded loop is that multiple threads can wait for new messages. Every thread is in a select loop on the socket, and at the end of the select loop, it tries to check if there are things to send (if you used `writeAndFlush` this will happen). By using a higher amount of threads, your send delay will decrease

Comment: @Ferrybig I see what you mean, for the sending part not for the receiving one. I will give it a try.

Comment: @Ferrybig I tried to use the default constructor, I can see that the determined number of threads is 16 (8 cores). However, only one thread is created for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: @Ferrybig Maybe the threads are created on demand? But, if it's the case, it means the bottleneck is not the single threaded event loop group. I'm not sure what is going on here.

Comment: Do you have access to a java profiler? It may show some hot spots in the code that require more investigation. Also, change the `Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(` to `channel.alloc().buffer(` so it uses your pooled buffer implementation

Comment: @Ferrybig Regarding the buffer allocator, I use wrappedBuffer() therefore the actual byte array is not copied, only wrapped.

Comment: @Ferrybig I'm not sure Netty is designed to use multiple threads for handling events on a single Channel. Are you sure about that fact? For me, it is proven by what I'm seeing now. Only one thread is used for handling events on the Channel, event using a multi threaded event loop group.

Comment: @Ferrybig It looks like I am right. See https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1706. I'm afraid my single thread is not able to handle both receive/send on this same Channel. I will try reverting to my original design where I create multiple Channels on the same interface (and same port). This way multiple threads are used (one for every Channel).